Limit definition of multiple derivatives handling more cases than iteratively differentiating -- is there a reason to prefer iterated derivatives?
This is something of a definition question in real analysis on some interval on $\mathbb{R}$.
I can define the second derivative of a function in two ways.
The first method iterates the derivative a couple times.
$$1. f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f'(x+h) - f'(x)}{h}$$
where $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$.
I believe this first definition assumes that $f'(x)$ exists in an interval about $x$.
However, I can imagine another definition of the second derivative that doesn't need $f'(x)$ to exist within an interval about $x$.
$$2. f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2 f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2}$$
I believe that definition 2 is more robust than definition 1; see for example this question.
For example, consider the following Dirichlet-esque function: $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$.
I believe that under definition $2$, $f(x)$ is twice differentiable at $x=0$. However, I believe that under definition $1$, $f(x)$ is not twice differentiable at $x=0$ because it is not once differentiable in an interval about $x=0$.
At least at first blush, I feel that I prefer the more robust second definition. However, I suspect there are good reasons to prefer the first definition.

What are the reasons to prefer the first definition with repeated derivatives over the second definition?

Please let me know if the question is opinion-based, and I'll try to remedy it.

It's called the Second Symmetric Derivative, and has a Wikipedia entry. I've never seen a use for it, but you're right that's it's defined more broadly than the second derivative in the usual sense.
